# Why did I lose 2 reputation points?

Tags: support, reputation

I can't see why I was at 71 points reputation a few hours ago, and am now at 69. I take my reputation seriously, and try to abide by the Stack Exchange rules. So I'm just curious as to why I lost 2 points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your profile to the following area:

[image: Imgur]

2 points were removed.  10K rep users will be able to see that the question has been removed by the question owner.

You had originally supplied an edit to the question which gained you 2 rep points.  When the OP removed the question, the 2 rep points was reversed.  This is normal behaviour.

Get cracking supplying some more great edits and you'll more than compensate your 2 rep loss. :)

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about a question being closed.